# Unable to Push notification by using GCM in android and C#

Tags: c#, android, .net, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have register my device in GCM, but my push GCM doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

asp.net side

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    send("APA91bHwwSLPkdIfqxW8gsosp1J1zgUUsHsgY1LFxetxig4Abo3MfYg7mdbvU3gqLMN5VhW08HvHKhxsHzRAqbRs7WtE6jAQux77XZpx9_1p20O9LMrzpa9mw_RmXoyfq5bkxsLEHO7n6ZGWHzmfzZxaimp46GwR8g");
}

void send(string regId)
{
    try
    {


    var applicationID = "tokyo-***se-***12";


    var SENDER_ID = "8500****7538";
    var value = "push message";
    WebRequest tRequest;
    tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    tRequest.Method = "post";
    tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));

    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

    // string postData = "{ 'registration_id': [ '" + regId + "' ], 'data': {'message': '" + txtMsg.Text + "'}}";
    string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regId + "";
    Console.WriteLine(postData);
    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

    dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

    lblStat.Text = sResponseFromServer;
    tReader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    tResponse.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception w)
    {
        Response.Write(w.Data);

    }
}
```

web.config

```
 <appSettings >
    <add key="GOOGLE_API_KEY" value="AIzaSyCuXwVivtKDKBqS2zxGCrD7Cc2Qwpjxgcw"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending the wrong authorization key here:

```
tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
```

You will need to change `applicationID` here to your API key, which you assigned to `GOOGLE_API_KEY`.

Lastly, you may want to consider hiding your actual API key from this StackOverflow post.